# Can't resolve the dependency

Tags: android, parse-platform, dependencies

My all other dependencies are successfully being resolved except-:

compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'

My build.gradle is -:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.transenigma.iskconapp"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            //multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
        compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
        compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0'
        compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    }
```

There is no problem in other libraries. Actually I made this project using internet without proxy and now I have changed Internet to that of proxy. although I have made changes in the settings but still these 2 dependencies are not being resolved. All other dependencies are successfully being resolved meaning that the internet is working properly. What is the issue.

Comment: use `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'`

Comment: set `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

Comment: Thanx it worked just by the first change. Can u tell me the difference between 1.+ and stating the exact version 1.12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`
2. **Use** `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'` instead of yours .

Actually `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'` is not **suitable (old )** for your `dependencies` & It's a ***Exact Version*** .